# jQuery on keyup and ignoring specific events

Tags: jquery

I have the following but it is not working. Does the jQuery event support the keyCode or do I need to get that someplace else?

```
$('#search-query').on('keyup',function(event){
  if(event.keyCode!==38 or event.keyCode!==40){
    search_autocomplete.call(this);
  }
});
```

How would I tell jQuery to just ignore if it's keyCode 38 or 40? Ultimately, I want to get this to like the search bar on http://www.linkedin.com/. Maybe just bootstrap it? http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead

thx in advance

Comment: Did you check the console for syntax errors in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `||` logical operator instead of `or` to join the condition in if statement.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8Qvgt/)**

**Change**

```
 if(event.keyCode!==38 or event.keyCode!==40){
```

**To**

```
 if(event.keyCode!==38 || event.keyCode!==40){
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you use both `event.keyCode`  and `event.which`  for cross browser compatibility

```
$('#search-query').on('keyup',function(event){

   var key = event.keyCode || event.which;

  if(key !==38 || key !==40){
    search_autocomplete.call(this);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at keypress...

```
$('#search-query').keypress(function (e) {
    if(e.which == 38  || e.which == 40) 
        search_autocomplete.call(this);
    }
});
```

Not tested but hopefully this helps